# python os.remove can not access the file

Tags: python, operating-system

Why am I getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\temp\py\tesst.py", line 8, in <module>
>       os.remove( PATH ) PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
>   'C:\temp\py\test.txt'

```
import os
PATH = r'C:\temp\py\test.txt'

f = open (  PATH,'w')
f.write('test\n')
f.close;

os.remove( PATH )
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `f.close` should be `f.close()`

Comment: Thank you!!  I guess I was reading a variable..

Comment: You were referencing the method instead of calling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `f.close` instead of `f.close()`. It would be better to open the file contextually so it will be closed automatically.

```
import os
PATH = r'C:\temp\py\test.txt'

with open(PATH, 'wb') as f:
    f.write('test\n')

os.remove(PATH)
```

Comment: Or heck, use the `tempfile` module's `TemporaryFile` or `NamedTemporaryFile` to get the deletion done for you as well.